# PHP-script with fopen throws 404 Not Found

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, fopen

I'm using a simple fopen statement to read a text file, but I get:

> *fopen(http://www.domain.nl/cees.txt): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found*

If I call `http://www.domain.nl/cees.txt` in my browser, the content displays without any problem, so the file exists (right?)....

I also tried cUrl, but it also returns a 404.

If I try my php-script on another host, it works just fine, so I figured I'd compare the settings for both hosts, but they are identical with *allow_url_fopen* On in both cases.

There's no htaccess and permissions on rootfolder are 755.

I'm pulling my hair out over this. Anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path?

Comment: a) domain.nl has anti-scraping protection being triggered by whatever host is getting the 404. b) proxy/gateway in between is filtering. so...do you have access to domain.nl's logs to see what gets logged for both the good and bad requests?

Comment: try using curl and passing an user-agent

Comment: Probably the `USER_AGENT` is not set and eventually an error is generated as the systems (correctly?) guessed that it has not been called via a browser/human.

Comment: Both hosts are on the same VPS (mine!). I have tried cUrl (with and without useragent) and file_get_content, but they all give a 404.

I've put the example online: http://www.aangenaam.nl/fopen.php

Comment: @Marc B: This is my own VPS and I have not installed any additional software or implemented a proxy.

Comment: @CeesRijken http://aangenaam.nl/ is unreachable.

Comment: @Bar-code: I was too hasty. Domain should be aangenaamvoedzaam.nl, so : www.aangenaamvoedzaam.nl/fopen.php

Comment: Is it just for the example that the txt file and the php file are on the same domain name ? Because there is no need to go through http:// to read a txt file from a php script on the same server. It's for sure a route problem. Try to run a script that execute gethostbyname('www.aangenaamvoedzaam.nl') on both server to see any IP  difference

Comment: Script is gonna be an extension of an API (another developer) that requires grabbing over http...

IP address resolve the same on both hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try:

The server that can't reach the file is behind a proxy. 
You may as well be behind the proxy and your browser is configure to go through. But not your php script.

Check your browser's config if it use a proxy. If so, then fopen has to use it too:

```
$opts= array(
                 'http' => array( 
                 'proxy' => 'tcp://proxyip:8080', 
                 'header' => array( 
                                     "Proxy-Authorization: Basic $auth" 
                                  ) 
                ) 
); 
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context)
```

Comment: I am not behind a proxy and neither is the server. The server is my own VPS.

Comment: Still no solution: www.aangenaamvoedzaam.nl/scripts/fopen.php throws 404, while same script on www.cornelisdigitaal.nl works fine. Both sites are on the same VPS, have identical DNS settings and allow_url_fopen is On....

Answer (score 0):

In a moment of clarity I decided to check the httpd.conf and found that the VirtualHost-line for the specified domain contained the IP4-address, but NOT the IP6-address.

I added the IP6-address, restarted Apache and I am happy little bunny!!!

Hope this helps someone else...